# Mapping JSON Data to Python Keyword Arguments

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to find a way of loading a JSON object and then mapping the keys to the keyword arguments of of a Python function.

Here's what a single case of this looks like now.

```
def load_new_category(self, filename):
    basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    filepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(basepath, "..", "JSON", filename))
    with open(filepath) as sample:
        self.create_new_category(is_active=case['is_active'],
                                 description=case['description'], page_title=case['page_title'],
                                 meta_keywords=case['meta_keywords'], meta_description=case['meta_description'],
                                 navigation_menu=case['navigation_menu'],
                                 parent_filter_setting=case['parent_filter_setting'],
                                 show_filter=case['show_filter'], sort_filter=case['sort_filter'])
```

This pattern is seen across many functions and I'm looking at for a way to generalize to any JSON file and function. Maybe a decorator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the `**kwargs` syntax here, since all your keyword arguments map one-on-one to your JSON object keys:

```
self.create_new_category(**case)
```